# Trying to get a different data set depending on value of a column

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm trying to construct a SQL statement that requires a condition but I'm not sure how to go about it. I looked at `If Else` statements but it can't return more than 1 value.

This is the best way I can explain it:

Needed:

```sql
PT.Due_Date,
PO.Initials,
PO.[Order No],
PO.[Ordered by],
PO.Supplier,
PT.QTY,
PT.[Description]
```

Here’s where it gets confusing (for me anyway):

```sql
IF (PO.Part Delivered == 0)
{
    /* All the required information has been retrieved. */
}
ELSE IF (PO.Part Delivered == 1)
{
    /* Get the following information from POD: */
    POD.[Delivery Date],
    POD.Delivered,
    POD.[Delivery Note],
    POD.[Received_By ]
}
```

Regarding the relationships between tables

```
[PO].[Order No] = [PT].[Order No]
[PT].[ID] = [POD].[Purchase_Table_ID]
```

No relationship between POD and PO.

Comment: What did you want to get? could you provide some sample data and expect result?

Comment: Show us your `CREATE TABLE` statements and sample data. We cannot really help you otherwise. What are your foreign-key constraints? How are `PO`, `PT`, and `POD`  related?

Comment: T-SQL doesn't use curly-braces, it uses Pascal-style `BEGIN` and `END` keywords for statement-blocks. But you should not be thinking of SQL as an imperative language: think of it as a _relational calculus_ for performing set-operations, without any kind of control-statements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a preface: don't think of SQL's `SELECT` queries as a place where you can perform logical branching on a row-by-row basis, instead think of it as a place for describing queries using only set-operations and joins.

<sub>(Doing *anything* in a relational database on a row-by-row basis is [invariably terrible](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/databases/sql-server/t-sql-programming-sql-server/rbar-row-by-agonizing-row/) anyway).</sub>

---

So what you would do is:

1. Get *all* of the `PO` rows that have `PO.[Part Delivered] = 0`, let's call these `undeliveredPOs`.
2. Separately, get *all* of the `PO` rows that have `PO.[Part Delivered] = 1`, and `INNER JOIN` them with `POD`, and let's call these `deliveredPOsWithPODs`.

   - As you haven't shown us your `CREATE TABLE` statements, I assume that your `PO` and `POD` tables have a `1:0-1` (one-to-zero-or-one) relationship such that:

     - `PO.[Order No]` is `PO`'s singular (not composite) `PRIMARY KEY`.
     - `POD.[Order No]` is `POD`'s singular (not composite) `PRIMARY KEY` *and also* is a `FOREIGN KEY` to `PO`.
     - This design (where you use a `FOREIGN KEY` column(s) as a `PRIMARY KEY` in a "child" tables) is a fundamental SQL database *design pattern* that prevents anomalous (i.e. duplicate) "child" data from ever happening in the first place.
3. Then concatenate (or rather: `UNION`) the `undeliveredPOs` and `deliveredPOsWithPODs` rows together.

   - As `deliveredPOsWithPODs` has more columns than `undeliveredPOs`, you'll need to add `NULL` values to make-up the difference.

If you're unfamiliar: in SQL, the set-operators (`UNION`, `INTERSECT`, `EXCEPT`) concatenate rows of data "vertically", while `JOIN` operators concatenate columns of data "horizontally" (if that helps).

So something like this, using named CTEs:

```sql
WITH posWithPts AS (
    
    SELECT
        -- PO:
        PO.Initials,
        PO.[Order No],
        PO.[Ordered by],
        PO.Supplier,
        -- PT:
        PT.Due_Date,
        PT.QTY,
        PT.[Description]
    FROM
        PO
        INNER JOIN PT ON PO.[SomeKey] = PT.[SomeKey]
),
undeliveredPOs AS (
    SELECT
        *
    FROM
        posWithPts
    WHERE
        [Part Delivered] = 0
),
deliveredPOsWithPODs AS (
    SELECT
        p.*,
        POD.[Delivery Date],
        POD.Delivered,
        POD.[Delivery Note],
        POD.[Received_By]
    FROM
        posWithPts AS p
        INNER JOIN POD ON p.[Order No] = POD.[Order No]
    WHERE
        p.[Part Delivered] = 1
)
SELECT
    u.*,
    -- Add NULLs for columns absent in undeliveredPOs:
    NULL AS [Delivery Date],
    NULL AS Delivered,
    NULL AS [Delivery Note],
    NULL AS [Received_By]
FROM
    undeliveredPOs AS u
UNION ALL /* Using `UNION ALL` instead of `UNION` for performance */
SELECT
    d.*
FROM
    deliveredPOsWithPODs AS d
```

My SQL above uses `*` to avoid repeating column names and for readability, but if this ever becomes a production-query then you should always explicitly list all column names (yes, it's tedious) and use `WITH SCHEMABINDING` to prevent database table design changes from breaking your query and/or resulting in incorrect results - this is most important when using `UNION` with mismatched columns.

---

If query-maintenance is not a concern, then the last 2 CTEs (`undeliveredPOs` and `deliveredPOsWithPODs`) can be inlined (but because `posWithPts` (the source view/CTE/derived-table/query) is referenced more than once it will remain as a named CTE), so the above query can be reduced down to this

```sql
WITH posWithPts AS (
    
    SELECT
        -- PO:
        PO.Initials,
        PO.[Order No],
        PO.[Ordered by],
        PO.Supplier,
        -- PT:
        PT.Due_Date,
        PT.QTY,
        PT.[Description]
    FROM
        PO
        INNER JOIN PT ON PO.[SomeKey] = PT.[SomeKey]
),
SELECT
    n.*,
    -- Add NULLs for columns absent in undeliveredPOs:
    NULL AS [Delivery Date],
    NULL AS Delivered,
    NULL AS [Delivery Note],
    NULL AS [Received_By]
FROM
    posWithPts AS n
WHERE
    n.[Part Delivered] = 0
UNION ALL
SELECT
    d.*,
    POD.[Delivery Date],
    POD.Delivered,
    POD.[Delivery Note],
    POD.[Received_By]
FROM
    posWithPts AS d
    INNER JOIN POD ON p.[Order No] = POD.[Order No]
WHERE
    d.[Part Delivered] = 1
```

Comment: Hi Dai, thanks for your help. My only issue now is the last bit where you inner join POD on p as POD doesn't have the order number in it, also Part Delivered is in Purchase Order not Purchase Table. Please see the revised question explanation for the relationships. TIA.